# Is there a word for someone/group of people that intentionally ignore an issue caused by them?

Tags: adjectives

I'm looking for a word/phrase similar to 'turning a blind eye' to describe someone/a group of people who intentionally ignore a problem caused by them because it's easier to ignore it than deal with it.

Specifically I'm looking for a word to pair with 'consumption' (consumer consumption) to be used when referencing the effects on the environment.

Thank you.

Comment: In the UK, the legal system is apt to use ***reckless** - [utterly unconcerned about the consequences of some action; without caution; careless*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reckless) for such people/behaviour.

Comment: It might be helpful to know how they ignore it...by denying ownership or by blaming someone or something else, or by being silent on any attempt to name them as the cause of the problem?  There are numerous words that can be used but context is an important part of the word choice.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I was looking for something to pair with 'consumption' (consumer consumption) when thinking of the environment. '**reckless** consumption' I think will work well.

Answer (score 5):

'**reckless**' was suggested by @FumbleFingers in the comments.

**reckless**: [utterly unconcerned about the consequences of some action; without caution; careless](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reckless)

Answer (score 1):

The adjective for such people is "rash" or, as mentioned by FF, "reckless".  Both words mean "careless to the point of irresponsibility".

> - rash - (adj) " acting without due consideration or thought" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rash)
>
> e.g.
>
> Their rash actions resulted in a serious accident that could have killed someone.
>
> Don't be rash about this decision. Take your time.
>
> It was rash of you to make that promise.

Comment: Also helpful, thank you @Centaurus. I would upvote but I don't have the required 15 reputation.

Comment: @TaylerHughes It's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: to have one's head in the sand.

Definition, origin and examples: https://www.oysterenglish.com/head-in-the-sand.html

Your example: The active purchasing habits of the community showed their head was in the sand regarding environmental well-being for the next seven generations.

Comment: This. (And the word is *ostrich*.)

Answer (score 0):

One often says that such a person, group etc. is "in denial". But they don't have to have caused it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The person or group is [*stonewalling*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/STONEWALLING) (WordWeb on line), evading the problem, question, or contact.